# Differentiability, finding values to satisfy a difference quotient

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

In my final review I found this question and it's causing me some difficulty.

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be 3 times differentiable with $f^{(3)}$ bounded, determine constants $a,b,c$ such that $f''(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{af(x-h)+bf(x)+cf(x+2h)}{h^2}$

My initial thought would be to apply L'hopital's Rule but this didn't get me any closer to finding the constants, only with some really long algebraic expressions for the higher derivative. Is there another way to do this or is L'hopital's the way to go?

Comment: Chances of an answer improve if you state the conditions exactly as given.

Comment: Thats all that's given in the question

Comment: Sure?  The $b(x)$ makes no sense is $b$ is a constant.  There isn't a $\lim_{h\to 0}$ somewhere in your problem?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the limit in, I'm thinking now I could use Taylor's theorem, and expand the $f(x-h)$, $f(x)$ and $f(x+2h)$, but what would I set this equal to to find the constants?

Comment: Ok, now it's a problem.  This is supposed to be true for all functions.  Try to check for (a)   $f(x)=1$ so that $f''(x)=0$, (ii) $f(x)=x$ so $f''(x)=0$, and (iii) $f(x)=x^2$ so $f''(x)=2$.  If it is true for these three functions that will impose pretty tight restrictions on what $a$, $b$ and $c$ would have to be.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. Rooney's first instincts (correct I believe) were to employ L'Hopital's rule.  He, perhaps, didn't like my simple idea and has posted the question again [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568841/could-someone-check-my-solution-for-finding-constant-of-a-difference-quotient) but with an
  solution using a Taylor expansion. (A completed solution  using that is posted there).

For others with this problem consider a more elementary approach.  If the condition holds for
all functions as described then it must hold for the very simple function  $f_1(x) = x^2$ for which $f_1''(x)=2$.

Check that $a$, $b$, and $c$ satisfy

$$2=f_1''(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{af_1(x-h)+bf_1(x)+cf_1(x+2h)}{h^2}$$
$$
 =  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{(a +b +c )x^2
+ 2(-a + 2c)h + (a + 4c)h^2  
  }{h^2}.$$

The only possible choice of $a$, $b$, and $c$ to make this work must satisfy the three equations
 $$
 \begin{array}{2}
a+b+c = 0 \\
-a + 2c =0 \\
a+4c = 2
 \end{array}
$$
  When we get some friend in high school to solve this system of equations, we find that  $a=2/3$, $b=−1$, and $c=1/3$.

Now the problem has changed since we know   the only possible choice of $a$, $b$, and $c$ to make this work.

> Show, for any  function $f$ with a continuous second derivative,
>   that $$ f''(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{ 2f(x-h) -3f(x)+ 
>   f(x+2h)}{3h^2}  .$$

L'Hopital's rule comes to mind (as it did to Mr Rooney)
and so we can ask another friend (this time in freshman calculus) to check that
$$
 \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{ 2f(x-h) -3f(x)+  f(x+2h)}{3h^2} 
$$
$$=  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{ -2f'(x-h) +  2f'
 (x+2h)}{6h } 
$$
$$
=  \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{  2f''(x-h) +  4f''
 (x+2h)}{6  } = f''(x).
$$

Do notice that we do not need the existence of the *third* derivative (nor that it be bounded). We do, however, need continuity of the second derivative to make this work.  (Weaker assumptions will also suffice but then you will have to abandon L'Hopital's rule.)

The extra unnecessary hypotheses were evidently there to encourage (and enable) a solution using Taylor series.